# I could not find joomla .xml file in the package

Tags: installation, packaging

Whenever I try to upload a Joomla templage on my site, I get the following message:

> Error! Could not find a Joomla! XML setup file in the package.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you getting your templates from the same site? Try installing a template from a different site and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the version of Joomla you're using and the first 20 lines of your XML file? I bet it's a version issue!

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the error 'cannot find not find XML setup file' appears is because Joomla can not find the TemplateDetails.xml file - because

- You have not unzipped the package
- You're trying to install a template which is a full Joomla!
  installation with sample data.
- You're trying to install an incompatible template.

Check these, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, check in the Template's folder to make sure templateDetails.xml exists.

If it does, make sure the template is for your version of Joomla.

If you have uploaded it by ftp, check that you have set the right permissions and/or try uploading by a different method.

If that fails, try uploading a different template so you can test if it is your specific template where the problem lies.